# Functor misses implicit value for parameter instance (only after sbt clean)

Tags: shapeless, scala-compiler, scala-cats

I did some experiments with Kittens (https://github.com/milessabin/kittens) and have issues with compiling my code. I receive the following error.

```
[error] ...danirey\scala\kittens\Kittens.scala:23: could not find implicit value for parameter instance: cats.Functor[danirey.scala.kittens.AdtDefns.Tree]
[error]     val funct = Functor[Tree]
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

The complete File is as follows

```
package danirey.scala.kittens

/**
  * @author Dani
  */
import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.AllSyntax
import cats.derived.functor._
import legacy._
import cats.derived.iterable.legacy._
import org.typelevel.discipline.scalatest.Discipline
import shapeless.cachedImplicit

object Kittens extends App {
  val ft = new FunctorExperiment()
  ft.print()
}

class FunctorExperiment extends AllSyntax {
  import AdtDefns._

  def print():Unit = {
    val funct = Functor[Tree]
    val tree: Tree[String] = Node(
        Leaf("Reto"),
        Node(
            Leaf("Sandra"),
            Leaf("Mike")
        )
    )

    println(funct.map(tree)(_.length))
  }
}
```

I have use the almost identical code in a ScalaTest which compiles without any issues.

```
package danirey.scala.kittens

import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.AllSyntax
import cats.derived.functor._
import legacy._
import cats.derived.iterable.legacy._
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.typelevel.discipline.scalatest.Discipline
import shapeless.cachedImplicit

/**
  * @author Dani
  */
class FunctorExperimentTest extends FunSuite with Discipline with AllSyntax {

  import AdtDefns._

  test("functors experiment") {
    val funct = Functor[Tree]

    val tree: Tree[String] = Node(
        Leaf("Reto"),
        Node(
            Leaf("Sandra"),
            Leaf("Mike")
        )
    )

    println(funct.map(tree)(_.length))
  }
}
```

My build.sbt looks as follows
    name := "shapeless-experiments"

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

exportJars := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.chuusai" % "shapeless_2.11" % "2.3.0",
  "org.typelevel" % "kittens_2.11" % "1.0.0-M2",
  "org.scalatest"   %% "scalatest"      % "3.0.0-M7" % "test"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-feature",
  "-language:higherKinds",
  "-language:implicitConversions",
  "-unchecked"
)
```

The most interesting thing is, that it compiles as part of an incremental compile.

If I comment line number 16, 23 and 32, then execute "sbt compile",
then remove the comments again and execute "sbt compile/package" it compiles and I can even execute the program. But as soon as I run "sbt clean", it will not compile anymore.

The AdtDefns Object is basically a copy of https://github.com/milessabin/kittens/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/cats/derived/adtdefns.scala
The relevant part is

```
object AdtDefns {
  sealed trait Tree[T]
  final case class Leaf[T](t: T) extends Tree[T]
  final case class Node[T](l: Tree[T], r: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
}
```

PS: Would be nice if someone could create a tag for scala-kittens

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug somewhere to me. 
My first reaction would be trying to rule out export hook, instead of `import cats.derived.functor._`, try  `import cats.derived.MkFunctor._` directly.

Comment: also 1.0.0-M3 (PR pending review) would be updated to scala 2.11.8 (with SI-2712 fix plugin), not sure if it's going to make an impact, but if this is a compiler bug...

Comment: Thanks @KailuoWang for the hint. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.
I'll wait for 1.0.0-M3 and then try it again together with the SI-2712
I guess no one would be interested in fixing a compiler bug in this area, when it will not occur with SI-2712 anyway.

Comment: to be clear, I am not sure if this is related to SI-2712. If there is any difference 1.0.0-M3 is gong to make in this issue, it would more likely be the 2.11.8 upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification. I will test again, as soon as 1.0.0-M3 is out.

Comment: FYI 1.0.0-M3 is out.

Comment: @KailuoWang Thank you. Unfortunately the upgrade to 1.0.0-M3 didn't resolve the issue.
Do you have any ideas how to further analysis this issue.

Comment: I am out of ideas (not many of them to begin with either).

Comment: @KailuoWang I still have the feeling, that I made a very basic mistake, or have a misunderstanding of kittens, which leads to this error.
Could you give me a pointer to a simple open-source project, which uses kittens as part of their implementation. Maybe I can find my error by looking at other peoples code.

Answer (score 0):

@DaniRey we use kittens in our projects but only the sequence part. I am not aware of any project that use kittens derivation.  What's your user case?

Comment: I don't have a specific use case - yet. I'm just eager to learn and understand new concepts.

Comment: @DaniRey I was thinking it might have something to day with the delayedInit in `App`, although I am not sure. If you want to use this in your real code I would say one work around could be adding an implicit derived instance in the companion object.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just changed the code to use a class with a `main` function instead of extending `App`, unfortunately it didn't change anything.
Regarding the implicit derived instance. I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what to do. Do you suggest to create a companion object for FunctorExperiment? But then adding a implicit derived instance of what?

Comment: I was suggesting adding a companion object for `Tree` and add something like 
```
implicit val f: Functor[Tree] = cats.derived.MkFunctor[Tree]
```
and in your tests, you don't need to import cats.derived any more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. I tried to change the code as you suggested, but now I receive the following compile error
`could not find implicit value for parameter mff: cats.derived.MkFunctor[danirey.scala.kittens.AdtDef
ns.Tree]`

I added the following companion object for Tree to adtdefns
`object Tree {
    implicit val f: Functor[Tree] = cats.derived.MkFunctor[Tree]
  }`

And simplified my Kittens object. The code is available at https://github.com/DaniRey/shapeless-experiments